# Undeclared identifier in Pine loop

Tags: loops, scripting, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I have this code:

```
// Average penetration

high_pen = for i = 0 to penetration_len

    penetration = high[i] - shortEma[i]
    sum = high_pen + penetration
    high_pen = penetration > 0 ? sum : 0
    high_pen

average_high_pen = high_pen / penetration_len
```

As you can see, I just want to get all penetration in a bullish trend. The compiler says that *high_pen* var is not declared in "*sum = high_pen + penetration*" sentence. It is a very simple loop which it only has to sum the penetration.

How can I do that correctly? How should I declare the  *high_pen* var and use it after the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Can't validate because your snippet is partial, but this should work:

```
// Average penetration

high_pen = 0.
for i = 0 to penetration_len
    penetration = high[i] - shortEma[i]
    sum = high_pen + penetration
    high_pen := penetration > 0 ? sum : 0

average_high_pen = high_pen / penetration_len
```